# Not able to login in a webapi controller, but can login via a azure page. Not sure why

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I am running in asp.net core v2.  I'm trying to login from a remote mobile app.  In my webapi controller, I have the following code to test to see if a userid/password combination is correct.  Unfortunately, I get a failed login.  I also tried CheckPasswordSignInAsync with the same result.  I can login from the web via an asp.net core v2 razor page.  The code and comments are below.  Question: Is there any code that looks wrong, or is there a column that I should double check in the identity database table that could keep me from logging in?

Thanks for any thoughts.  :-)

The following webapi code is what I am trying to use to login via a webapi.  I am unable to login from this code.
Webapi code:

```
                var da = new DataAccess();
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = lu.UserName, };

            var res = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, lu.PassWord, false, false);
            if (res.Succeeded)
            {
                login.LoggedIn = true;
                var u = da.UserInfo(lu.UserName);
                login.UserToken = u.UserToken;
            }
            return login;
```

This is the code that I am using to login from an azure razor page.  This code is allowing me to login.
Login from the web:

```
var appUser = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = userName };
var signin = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, pwd, true, false);
```

This is the code that I am using to create a single test user.

Code to create a user:

```
var email = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
var pwd = "yyyyyyyyyy";
var foundUser = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email).Result;
if (foundUser == null)
{
    var res = userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser() { UserName = email, Email = email }, pwd).Result;
    var user = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email).Result;
    user.UserToken = Guid.NewGuid();
    foreach (var role in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Roles)))
    {
        if (!(userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role).Result))
        {
            var iResult = userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling PasswordSignInAsync(Username, Password, false, false) seems to have solved my problem.  I'll pass this along incase someone needs it later.

Maybe someone has a better way to do this as well.

Thanks.